# PHP (possibly UTF8) Encoding/Decoding issue - single characters displaying

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, filemaker

I have a string I'm pulling from a Filemaker database that's supposed to read

> Pete Dye–designed golf course

but my array returns it as

> Pete Dyeâ€“designed golf course

i think this has to do with encoding but i'm not sure...how can i correct this error? if it comes down to it, i don't mind making an str_replace() array for all of the issues, but it would be nice to not have to find the exceptions individually.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty workaround is to use [`iconv`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) function with `//TRANSLIT` parameter:

```
// assuming your page is using `ISO-8859-1` character set
echo iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", "Pete Dyeâ€“designed golf course");
// Pete Dye-designed golf course
```

Note that the three byte sequence `â€“` is converted to a `-` which is the approximate representation of the unicode `–`.

Comment: small issue though: this works great echoing just the way you have it, but when i bring in the full string ("
Enjoy hiking, yoga, tennis, bocce, two outdoor heated pools, a Pete Dyeâ€“designed golf course, Spa Aiyana, and the signature Bee Experience.") it cuts off after Dye...any ideas? and THANKS!

Comment: no php error, i'm starting to question whether the encoding is utf8 at all though

Answer (score 0):

There may not be anything wrong with it, but the browser is displaying it as such. Make sure your page has this before you print_r or var_dump your array:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Comment: yes i'm using print_r and viewing the source. i should have probably mentioned that the text is being sent to gd as well, so a meta tag won't work in this case.

Comment: yes, this produces mixed results, the closest of which gets me "Dye?designed". i just assumed that the encoding is utf8 because of a few google searches...do you think it's possible it's in a different encoding?